# What do we call parents who lose their child?

Tags: single-word-requests

When a child loses his parents, he is referred to as an orphan.

If a woman loses her husband, she is considered a widow.

But if a parent loses their child, what do we call them? Childless? Childless doesn't make much sense, as if the parents never had children to begin with.

Comment: If they are left childless as a result of a child's death, it would be "tragically childless" or "mortally childless".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of a specific word for this situation, but ***bereaved parents*** fits. To *bereave* means to suffer a profound loss, especially through the death of a loved one. Associating the word with "parent" will indicate the loss of a child.

Answer (score 4):

If it is an only child we can use the word **shidu** (or shidu parents) which has been recently introduced into English from Chinese.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shidu_(parents)) explains:

> Shidu (失独) is a phenomenon denoting the loss of a parent's only child. The parents who have lost their only child are known as shidu fumu in China.

This might be a bit more specific than what you're looking for but can't hurt to consider.