# Is there a single word to describe the loss of a child?

Tags: single-word-requests

#### To my knowledge,

There is no single word that describes a "person who has lost a child."

> We have "widow" and "widower" for a person whose spouse had died. We have "orphan" for a child whose parent or parents have died. [Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=a+person+who+has+lost+a+child&oq=a+person+who+has+lost+a+child&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1063j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

According to the quora question, the closest word is in Arabic: ثَكْلَى (thakla) which translates as "bereaved mother."

---

**Though** bereaved does not adequately describe 'loss of child' as it's definition is:

> [to] be deprived of a loved one through a profound absence, especially due to the loved one's death.

---

My questions are:

- If there is a word, what is it?
- If there is not a word, what word would Shakespeare have made up to convey the idea?

Comment: Very closely related: [What do we call parents who lose their child?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193291/what-do-we-call-parents-who-lose-their-child) and [Word for grieving parents?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62469/word-for-grieving-parents) and [What is the inverse of an orphan?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231807/what-is-the-inverse-of-an-orphan)

Comment: Didn't catch that one, my apologies. I hate asking duplicate questions.

Comment: But you did ask what word Shakespeare used, or would have wrote and there might be someone who knows the answer to that one.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of related, now-obsolete terms that Shakespeare might have used, all related to the Latin *orbus* meaning bereavement. These include most notably<sup>1</sup>

> **† orbity, *n.*** *Obs.* A bereavement, esp. the loss of a child; the state or condition of being bereaved. Also (esp. in later use): childlessness. [Attestations from 1597 to 1804]
>
> **† orb, *adj.*** *Obs. rare.* Childless. [Only two attestations, one in 1607—spelled *orbe*—and one in 1660]

Neither of these is an exact parallel for terms like *widow* or *orphan*, however. Interestingly, the latter of these shares an Indo-European root with *orbus*. Perhaps Shakespeare could have coined a parallel term *orban* for parents bereaved of their child(ren).

Alternatively, some compound term might work; perhaps something like *orbe-
mother* for a bereaved mother.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Definitions from the Oxford English Dictionary: *OED Online*, Oxford University Press, March 2017.

<sup>2</sup> Other possibilities, but these are pure invention: *orbant* or *orphent*, combining *orb* or *orphan* and *parent*; *orbither*, combining *orb/orbity* with *mother/father*.

Unfortunately, many possible options are problematic for modern English-speakers, due to the similarity to the unrelated words *orb* and *orbit*. One possible solution would be to stick closer to the Latin, for example *mater orba* or *orba mater*. A question on the Latin SE might get more plausible suggestions along these lines.

Comment: How is this relevant to contemporary English?

Comment: @Lambie the OP asked what word would Shakespeare have used.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Actually, it says what word would Shakespeare "have made up". Also, there are several searchable, full-text Shakespeare sites. So, it's a guess, right?

Comment: @Lambie, the body of the answer is not a guess, it's part of the attested history of the language. I took the reference to Shakespeare to mean the OP was interested in archaic/obsolete terms from approximately Elizabethan times, in addition to current terms. The site allows questions about the [history](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/history/info) of the language. The "guesses" are in a footnote, as they are, in fact, purely opinion, which is not a great fit for the site.